# How to recover files from Ubuntu after resizing my Windows partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

My laptop has dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 
I tried to resize my partition with AOMEI Partition Assistant and I can't find my ubuntu files anymore.

In the boot screen appears "minimal bash like editing is supported etc "

I tried booting in live mode and I did boot-repair, but still not working.

This is the link from boot-repair : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vFTbDHbcQ5/

Any ideas how can I recover at least my files from ubuntu?

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser! How exactly did you resize your partition (how much space did you add)? What was your Ubuntu partition before that, how big it was, what filesystem did it have?

Comment: Before I had 1 partition with 200 GB, where Linux and Windows werre, and a 290GB unallocated space. I had to make the 200GB partition adjacent with the other and that is why I used AOMEI. I don't  really know how Linux and Windows shared the 200GB partition...